# Two fair dice roll. Lower score discarded. In case of tie, either die is discarded. Compute the mean value of the remaining number

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, dice

"Two fair dice are thrown and the one with a lower score is discarded. In case of a tie, either one of them is discarded. Compute the mean value of the remaining number."

I know how to calculate the expected mean which would be 7. I'm stuck on the "remaining value" part when the lower score die is discarded. How would I calculate the mean value of the remaining number? Any clarity is appreciated!

Comment: If all else fails, you could simply list all $36$ possible throws and compute the mean directly.  Alonmg the way, I expect you'll think of ways to speed the computation.

Comment: Hi @lulu , thats what I did and got 7 as my answer. Maybe I'm misinterpreting my own question, but whats throwing me off is the fact its asking for the mean of whats leftover once the lower number die is discarded.

Comment: How could the mean be $7$?  The maximal score is $6$.  To get the rules straight:  if you roll $(a,b)$ the result is $\max(a,b)$.

Comment: 2 dice, 36 possible outcomes. Therefore the expected mean overall:
2(1/36) + 3(2/36) + 4(3/36) + 5(4/36) + 6(5/36) + 7(6/36) + 8(5/36) + 9(4/36) + 10(3/36) + 11(2/36) + 12(1/36) = 7

Comment: You appear to be ignoring the rules.  If, say, you throw a $2$ and a $5$ you discard the $2$ so your result is a $5$.  (Note that $5=\max (2,5)$).  There is no way to get a result greater than $6$.

Comment: ok so following that logic, how would the mean be calculated?

Comment: I repeat my first comment:  it is not difficult to simply list the $36$ possible dice throws and compute the mean that way.  Along the way, you should spot ways to greatly speed the computation.

Comment: As a (minor) variant of that, count the rolls that give each particular result.  The only way to get a $1$, for example, is to throw $(1,1)$.  Of course there are lots of ways to get a $6$.

Answer (score 0):

What has to be calculated here is just the maximum of the two dice. I don't see how to speed up the computation, either. Just get the distribution of the maximum number and you're good to go.